# Update Spinner items to the database.?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, spinner

i have a spinner that loads items from the SQLite database. it works fine.
then i have a edittext to get the selected spinner item to that edittext. its also woks.
then i want to change the edit text value and update that spinner item to the database.
so how to do that. please any help. thnx

Answer (score 0):

You should make sql update query. As you already get spinner items from DB, you should know how to make queries. To make update query, you have to call db.[update()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) method.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say,you have populated `Spinner spinner` with data from database.And you have `EditText editText` and `Button button` to update spinner values.Then you can achieve this something like below:

```
...
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long arg3) {

                //code to display the selected item in EditText
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

        }
});
selectDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                 DatabaseCreator dbcreator=new DatabaseCreator(context);
                 SQLiteDatabase sqdb=dbcreator.getWritableDatabase();   

                 ContentValues values=new ContentValues();

                 //Update respective fields in database 
                 values.put("field_1",newValue1);
                 values.put("field_2",newValue2);

                 long suceess=sqdb.update( "table_name", values, KEY_ID+"='"+id+"'", null);
                 // you can place any condition in place of KEY_ID+"='"+id+"'" as third argument in above statement

                 if(success!=0)
                 {
                      //repopulate spinner here
                 }  
        }
});
...
```

**DatabaseCreator.class:**

```
public class DatabaseCreator extends  SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private static final String DB_NAME="db_name";
    private static final int DB_VER=2;

    private static final String TABLE_1="create table table_1(...);"; //complete create query goes here

    public DatabaseCreator(Context context) {
        super(context,DB_NAME, null, DB_VER);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {

        database.execSQL(TABLE_1);      
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int arg1, int arg2) {

            database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS db_name");
        onCreate(database);
    }
}
```